# Laravel 5.5 : Storage::put , file_put_contents error :failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: storage, laravel-5.5

Running a dev win 7 machine.

When trying to store a file with laravel :

```
$file_store ='/srt/SiteName/df01c6a46702639c/0f3e86c003030527.srt
$file_data = srt file content

    Storage::put($file_store, $file_data)
```

I get the following error :

```
 file_put_contents(E:\Projects\2017\releases\storage\app\srt/SiteName/df01c6a46702639c/0f3e86c003030527.srt"): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

When I check on the local disk , it did create the following directories :

```
SiteName/df01c6a46702639c/
```

But it just will not store the file, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put($file_store, $file_data);
```